# Rails 4.0 integration test fails at session setup only during rake test:all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, session, integration-testing

I'm having the following integration test which works fine as long as I only run "rake test:integration":

```
test "login for address and browse site" do
  get_via_redirect '/'
  assert_equal '/sessions/new', path
  post_via_redirect '/sessions', session: {
    street: 'Test Ave', number: '4',
    two_weeks: '0', selection: 'something'
  }
  assert_equal '/schedules/public', path
end
```

When running only my integration tests everything is fine. When I run all tests through "rake test" or "rake test:all", it fails:

```
  1) Failure:
UserFlowsTest#test_login_for_address_and_browse_site
[.../test/integration/user_flows_test.rb:15]:
Expected: "/schedules/public"
  Actual: "/sessions/new"

123 tests, 648 assertions, 1 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

I suppose it has something to do with how sessions are handled during testing. Some of the functional tests work with sessions, but running "rake test:functionals test:integration" doesn't show the problem. Sessions are setup to use cookie store through `initializers/session_store.rb`, so I'd expect sessions work local and isolated to each individual test.

However, running `rake test:units test:integration` shows the problem, too. But I don't see what could be causing such an issue.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check under the hood to see what `rake test` does as opposed to `rake test:integration` in your app. In apps I am familiar with `rake test:integration` actually builds up your assets into something similar to public/assets... runs the test with those linked dependencies... then rm -r public/assets. Whereas `rake test:all` may not be building/linking the proper dependencies.

One solution would be to create a custom task that would programmatically step through each rake task you wanted to run, building up your assets before you run the integration tests, and then cleaning up afterwards. Or simply calling `rake test:integration`...